# If I use targetFramework="4.5" why are my pages still served in 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, iis

My Web Application is targeting framework 4.5 and runs perfectly on the local IIS, but when I publish the the server (Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.0), I see that the webpage is still rendered as 4.0, which is a problem because web.optimization only works on 4.5.

[image: The webpage renders as asp.net 4.0]

I made sure that asp.net 4.5 is installed on my web server. My application pool is 4.0 integrated, which I read still means 4.5.  So I'm not sure what else I can do, since IIS doesn't have a dropdown for the server or website saying, "Use ASP.NET 4.5."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET Framework 4.5 uses Common Language Runtime 4.0, with some additional runtime features released with 4.5. Same is case for .Net 3.0 and 3.5 which uses CLR 2.0 hence you wont see seperate versions for these releases i.e. 3.0,3.5 and 4.5. So even if you get 4.0 in response headers that doesnt mean its not being processed with .Net 4.5.